# PHPExcel Comment

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to insert a comment with in a cell. I am trying following code to comment but it is not showing comment within created excel.
I am creating .xls extension.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment('E11')->setAuthor('Efusionsoft');
$objCommentRichText = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment('E11')->getText()->createTextRun('PHPExcel:');
$objCommentRichText->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment('E11')->getText()->createTextRun("\r\n");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment('E11')->getText()->createTextRun('Total amount on the current invoice, excluding VAT.');
```

Comment: That is just the sample code from the documentation, show the rest of your code.

Comment: @AndreKR Thanks. Whole code is too big to be here. Everything is working fine but comment is not being shown

Comment: Wait for Mark Baker to look at this question. He will surely answer this question satisfactorily, though i would like to make it prestine that i am not underestimating anyone else.

Comment: Ok, you're right, that sample code doesn't work with the Excel5 writer. And there is no support for comments in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no support for comments in the Excel5 writer. Use the Excel2007 writer to create an .xlsx file.

Comment: Oh yes!. Thanks a lot. I was struggling with the same thing mentioned in this question and you solved it. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @AndreKR can you provide example

Comment: There are plenty of [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md) on the web. Please note the PHPExcel is deprecated in favor of PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheets.